# how to exclude an image from facebook sharer

Tags: html, facebook

even though i use this meta `<link rel="image_src" href="myimage"/>` in my page, facebook sharer selects an image that i am using for ajax loading (load.gif)

how can i exclude that image ?

Comment: For the sake of completeness - here is another solution to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19428173/601466

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of including it in the HTML, try adding that load.gif to the page dynamically using Javascript when you need to display it. This way Facebook will not see this image in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Using Leventix suggestion, only on the home page I had to use javascipt to load images to prevent facebook from loading other images for "sharing" images found on the home page.  Here's what I did.

In the head, I explicitately stated the image that is to be used when Facebook share link images apear using:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="/images/site.gif" />
```

And then all references to images on the home page I loaded like this:

```
<img alt="" onLoad="imgSrc(this, '<?php print base_path().path_to_theme() ?>/images/gall1.jpg');" src="/images/spacer.png" />

<script>function imgSrc(img, src) {if (img.src.search("spacer.png") > 0){img.src = src;}};</script>
```